# GCM registration id in emulator or mobile show result "OK" as success message using phonegap pushnotification plugin

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

hi i am building application using cordova but fadeup to grab this issue any one know whats exactly problem, i have also check each n every thing n android manifest.xml kindly if some one faced this issue guid me thanks in advance.

i also used correct projectnumber.

Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf (has extras) } U=0: not found but it give

```
 Controller.js

/**
 * Author: hollyschinsky
 * twitter: @devgirfl
 * blog: devgirl.org
 * more tutorials: hollyschinsky.github.io
 */
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaPush, $cordovaDialogs, $cordovaMedia, $cordovaToast, ionPlatform, $http) {
    $scope.notifications = [];

    // call to register automatically upon device ready
    ionPlatform.ready.then(function (device) {
        $scope.register();
    });


    // Register
    $scope.register = function () {
        var config = null;

        if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
            config = {
                "senderID": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "ecb":"onNotificationGCM"
                // project URL like: https://console.developers.google.com/project/434205989073
            };
        }
        else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
            config = {
                "badge": "true",
                "sound": "true",
                "alert": "true",
                "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
            }
        }

        $cordovaPush.register(config).then(function (result) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(result))
            console.log("Register success " + result);

            $cordovaToast.showShortCenter('Registered for push notifications');
            $scope.registerDisabled=true;
            // ** NOTE: Android regid result comes back in the pushNotificationReceived, only iOS returned here
            if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
                $scope.regId = result;
                storeDeviceToken("ios");
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("Register error " + err)
        });
    }

    // Notification Received
    $scope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function (event, notification) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify([notification]));
        if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
            handleAndroid(notification);
        }
        else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
            handleIOS(notification);
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.notifications.push(JSON.stringify(notification.alert));
            })
        }
    });

    // Android Notification Received Handler
    function handleAndroid(notification) {
        // ** NOTE: ** You could add code for when app is in foreground or not, or coming from coldstart here too
        //             via the console fields as shown.
        console.log("In foreground " + notification.foreground  + " Coldstart " + notification.coldstart);
        if (notification.event == "registered") {
            $scope.regId = notification.regid;
            storeDeviceToken("android");
        }
        else if (notification.event == "message") {
            $cordovaDialogs.alert(notification.message, "Push Notification Received");
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.notifications.push(JSON.stringify(notification.message));
            })
        }
        else if (notification.event == "error")
            $cordovaDialogs.alert(notification.msg, "Push notification error event");
        else $cordovaDialogs.alert(notification.event, "Push notification handler - Unprocessed Event");
    }

    // IOS Notification Received Handler
    function handleIOS(notification) {
        // The app was already open but we'll still show the alert and sound the tone received this way. If you didn't check
        // for foreground here it would make a sound twice, once when received in background and upon opening it from clicking
        // the notification when this code runs (weird).
        if (notification.foreground == "1") {
            // Play custom audio if a sound specified.
            if (notification.sound) {
                var mediaSrc = $cordovaMedia.newMedia(notification.sound);
                mediaSrc.promise.then($cordovaMedia.play(mediaSrc.media));
            }

            if (notification.body && notification.messageFrom) {
                $cordovaDialogs.alert(notification.body, notification.messageFrom);
            }
            else $cordovaDialogs.alert(notification.alert, "Push Notification Received");

            if (notification.badge) {
                $cordovaPush.setBadgeNumber(notification.badge).then(function (result) {
                    console.log("Set badge success " + result)
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log("Set badge error " + err)
                });
            }
        }
        // Otherwise it was received in the background and reopened from the push notification. Badge is automatically cleared
        // in this case. You probably wouldn't be displaying anything at this point, this is here to show that you can process
        // the data in this situation.
        else {
            if (notification.body && notification.messageFrom) {
                $cordovaDialogs.alert(notification.body, "(RECEIVED WHEN APP IN BACKGROUND) " + notification.messageFrom);
            }
            else $cordovaDialogs.alert(notification.alert, "(RECEIVED WHEN APP IN BACKGROUND) Push Notification Received");
        }
    }

    // Stores the device token in a db using node-pushserver (running locally in this case)
    //
    // type:  Platform type (ios, android etc)
    function storeDeviceToken(type) {
        // Create a random userid to store with it
        var user = { user: 'user' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000) + 1), type: type, token: $scope.regId };
        console.log("Post token for registered device with data " + JSON.stringify(user));
        alert(JSON.stringify(user));
        //$http.post('http://192.168.1.16:8000/subscribe', JSON.stringify(user))
        //    .success(function (data, status) {
        //        console.log("Token stored, device is successfully subscribed to receive push notifications.");
        //    })
        //    .error(function (data, status) {
        //        console.log("Error storing device token." + data + " " + status)
        //    }
        //);
    }

    // Removes the device token from the db via node-pushserver API unsubscribe (running locally in this case).
    // If you registered the same device with different userids, *ALL* will be removed. (It's recommended to register each
    // time the app opens which this currently does. However in many cases you will always receive the same device token as
    // previously so multiple userids will be created with the same token unless you add code to check).
    function removeDeviceToken() {
        var tkn = {"token": $scope.regId};
        //$http.post('http://192.168.1.16:8000/unsubscribe', JSON.stringify(tkn))
        //    .success(function (data, status) {
        //        console.log("Token removed, device is successfully unsubscribed and will not receive push notifications.");
        //    })
        //    .error(function (data, status) {
        //        console.log("Error removing device token." + data + " " + status)
        //    }
        //);
    }

    // Unregister - Unregister your device token from APNS or GCM
    // Not recommended:  See http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg-why
    //                   and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/unregisterForRemoteNotifications
    //
    // ** Instead, just remove the device token from your db and stop sending notifications **
    $scope.unregister = function () {
        console.log("Unregister called");
        removeDeviceToken();
        $scope.registerDisabled=false;
        //need to define options here, not sure what that needs to be but this is not recommended anyway
//        $cordovaPush.unregister(options).then(function(result) {
//            console.log("Unregister success " + result);//
//        }, function(err) {
//            console.log("Unregister error " + err)
//        });
    }


})






    AndroidManifest.xml

    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="org.devgirl.push.sample" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
            <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity" />
            <receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="org.devgirl.push.sample" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
        </application>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        <permission android:name="org.devgirl.push.sample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
        <uses-permission android:name="org.devgirl.push.sample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    </manifest>
```

Comment: You are saying you are getting ok , instead of registration id ? Share your code in question instead of `AndroidManifest.xml`, any change required in this file is auto generated by plugin, when you install it. So no issue with this `.xml`

Comment: Plus also share plugin link, which one you are using.

Comment: https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSample

plugin link that i am using

Comment: First of all you are using old client side plugin. I am adding answer with latest plugin. You even do not need to use ngCordova wrapper for that.

Comment: ok ajaz thanx so give me link new code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use latest pushplugin : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Command to install: `ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push` 
Add following line to register your device:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "here-goes-your-sender-id"}});
```

that line registered your device, and `registration` event will be generated towards application. Receive your registration id through this code:

```
push.on('registration', function(data) {
        // data.registrationId, here you can put your logic to save this registration id
});
```

To handle notifications or error use this code

```
push.on('notification', function(data) {
        // data.message,
        // data.title,
        // data.count,
        // data.sound,
        // data.image,
        // data.additionalData
    });

push.on('error', function(e) {
        // e.message
});
```

Now i gave answer of using latest plugin, but nothing is wrong with your code which you provide, thing is you are looking registration token at wrong place. You are looking for registration token here

```
$cordovaPush.register(config).then(function (result) {
```

But for android, above mentioned line only register device, this part does not return token, here is where you receive token (i changed your $scope.$on with $rootScope.$on , so you can receive these events if you are not in this controller ).

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function (event, notification) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify([notification]));
        if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
            handleAndroid(notification);
        }
        else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
            handleIOS(notification);
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.notifications.push(JSON.stringify(notification.alert));
            })
        }
    });
```

And here is your handleAndroid where you see wether this notification was message or device toke.

```
function handleAndroid(notification) {
        // ** NOTE: ** You could add code for when app is in foreground or not, or coming from coldstart here too
        //             via the console fields as shown.
        console.log("In foreground " + notification.foreground  + " Coldstart " + notification.coldstart);
        if (notification.event == "registered") {
            $scope.regId = notification.regid;
            storeDeviceToken("android");
        }
```

`notification.regid;` is your device token. Which you save on server side to send notifications.

Comment: when handleAndroid will be called?